# Sklearn's SimpleImputer can't retrieve imputation values when in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, sklearn-pandas, imputation

I am trying to print out all of the imputation values after fitting with `SimpleImputer`.  When using `SimpleImputer` by itself, I can retrieve these from the instance's `statistics_` attribute.

This works fine:

```
s = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
s.fit(df[['feature_1', 'feature_2']])
print(s.statistics_)
```

However, I'm unable to do so when using `SimpleImputer` in a pipeline.

This does not work:

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('simple_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_features = ['feature_3']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('simple_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))])

clf.fit(df[numeric_features + categorical_features], df['target'])

print(clf.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers[0][1].named_steps['simple_imputer'].statistics_)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-523-7390eac0d9d6> in <module>
     19 clf.fit(df[numeric_features + categorical_features], df['target'])
     20 
---> 21 print(clf.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers[0][1].named_steps['simple_imputer'].statistics_)

AttributeError: 'SimpleImputer' object has no attribute 'statistics_
```

I believe I am grabbing the correct instance of the fitted `SimpleImputer` object.  Why can't I retrieve its `statistics_` attribute to print out the imputation values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find it easier to use 'dot' notation when working with `sklearn` pipelines, not least because you get autocomplete to help you navigate the structure/attributes of the pipeline.  It also has the added bonus (in my opinion), of being more readable.

You can use the following line to access the `statistics_` attribute of the `SimpleImputer`:

```
imputation_vals = (
    clf
    .named_steps
    .preprocessor
    .named_transformers_
    .num
    .named_steps
    .simple_imputer.statistics_
)
```